# How to check type of variable? Python

Tags: python, variables

I need to do one thing if `args` is integer and ather thing if `args` is string.

How can i chack type? Example:

```
def handle(self, *args, **options):

        if not args:
           do_something()
        elif args is integer:
           do_some_ather_thing:
        elif args is string: 
           do_totally_different_thing()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of, `*args` is always a list. You want to check if its content are strings?

```
import types
def handle(self, *args, **options):
    if not args:
       do_something()
    # check if everything in args is a Int
    elif all( isinstance(s, types.IntType) for s in args):
       do_some_ather_thing()
    # as before with strings
    elif all( isinstance(s, types.StringTypes) for s in args):
       do_totally_different_thing()
```

It uses `types.StringTypes` because Python actually has two kinds of strings: unicode and bytestrings - this way both work.

In Python3 the builtin types have been removed from the `types` lib and there is only one string type.
This means that the type checks look like `isinstance(s, int)` and `isinstance(s, str)`.

Comment: Is there any preference for using `isinstance(s,types.IntType)` over just `isinstance(s,int)` or is it just to be consistent with what you mentioned for the two types of strings?  Just curious.

Comment: Your solution is not compatible with python 3.1!

Comment: @Brent Nash yeah just consistency. Run `int is types.IntType` in the interpreter.

Comment: Actually testing for `basestring` (the superclass of `str` and `unicode`) instead of `types.StringTypes` should work as well.

Comment: @Philipp: Using the ABC instead of Inheritance is actually more general: Anything that is registered with the `StringTypes` ABC would work in the test. It's not really a significant difference (who registers with ABCs anyways?), but it's a step in the  direction of languages that do very cool things with types (see typeclasses in Haskell, which are very similar to ABCs).

Comment: `StringTypes` is a tuple, not an ABC. (But of course you can say `types.StringTypes += int,`.)

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to do it in a more Pythonic way without using `type` or `isinstance`(preferred because it supports inheritance):

```
if not args:
     do_something()
else:
     try:
        do_some_other_thing()
     except TypeError:
        do_totally_different_thing()
```

It obviously depends on what `do_some_other_thing()` does.

Answer (score 0):

```
type(variable_name)
```

Then you need to use:

```
if type(args) is type(0):
   blabla
```

Above we are comparing if the type of the variable args is the same as the literal `0` which is an integer, if you wish to know if for instance the type is long, you compare with `type(0l)`, etc.

Comment: I dont understand. 
How to  use it?

Comment: Ugh. `type(2)` is `int`, but anyway, `type` is Not Good Python

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you are expecting an integer/string argument, you shouldn't swallow it into `*args`. Do

```
def handle( self, first_arg = None, *args, **kwargs ):
    if isinstance( first_arg, int ):
        thing_one()
    elif isinstance( first_arg, str ):
        thing_two()
```

Answer (score 0):

No one has mentioned it, but the Easier to Ask For Forgiveness principle probably applies since I presume you'll be doing something with that integer:

```
def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        #Do some integer thing
    except TypeError:
        #Do some string thing
```

Of course if that integer thing is modifying the values in your list, maybe you should check first. Of course if you want to loop through `args` and do something for integers and something else for strings:

```
def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
    for arg in args:
        try:
            #Do some integer thing
        except TypeError:
            #Do some string thing
```

Of course this is also assuming that no other operation in the try will throw a TypeError.

Comment: actually i've mentioned it :)